# boolean slice no longer part of blender 2.8?

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to blender and I'm using it to sculpt an object for 3D printing. As part of the design I want to use a **plane** to **boolean slice** the object in two objects like in minute 1:30 in this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H6_FRC5RdA , but for some reason I cannot find the same button in blender 2.8, has this function been moved, removed or replaced? Where is it now or what's the new approach to achieve this? The only options in the modifier menu are: insersect, union, difference. What happened to slice and subtract?

I know you can use knife and bisect, but I liked the boolean slice better because it seemed to be a better way to split objects in a more controlled manner. By the way I come from the engineering CAD world so this is all new to me.

Thanks,
Nestor

Comment: The tools belong to the Bool Tool plugin. They do not come with the vanilla B 2.80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's using the Bool Tool Plugin

The tools belong to the Bool Tool plugin. They do not come with the vanilla B 2.80, you'll have to install a compatible version of the plugin.

You can find it here:
https://gist.github.com/derappelt/603883d70a56c5d1f5080c2980bb5b9f

Then you should look for the Object menu, at the bottom you'll find the BoolTool operators you were looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download a script or plug-in anymore, it's now shipped by default.

Just open up the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*), search for "Bool Tool" in the Add-ons and activate it. Now you can use the short cut (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) or you can find it at the bottom of the object menu.

Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/bool_tools.html